# ArcPy comparing two databases and deleting and appending data from one to another

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, loading

I currently am working on trying to ingest data from a client into our database. The schemas are almost the same so I want to compare feature class to feature class and want to delete and append the new data into my SDE.

Current error:     arcpy.DeleteRows_management(outFCpath)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.6\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 18055, in DeleteRows
raise e
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000582: Error occurred during execution.

```py
import arcpy,os

# Input your environmental DB connection here
arcpy.env.workspace = r'K:\1_DATA\EnvironmentalData\FairchildAFB_4_0_3_1_containsCUI.gdb'
# Stores all datasets in your environemtnal database in 'envFDs'
envFDs = arcpy.ListDatasets()

# Input your GIO DB connection here. HAS TO BE GIO
sdeWS = r'Database Connections\GIO.sde'

for ds in envFDs:
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=ds):
        inFCpath = os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, ds, fc)
        outFCpath = os.path.join(sdeWS, 'GIO.' + ds, 'GIO.' + fc)
        #print (outFCpath)

        #Don't need try except - outer if/else check if exists, inner checks if empty
        if arcpy.Exists(outFCpath):         
            result1 = arcpy.GetCount_management(outFCpath)
            result2 = arcpy.GetCount_management(inFCpath)
            print(outFCpath + " exists")

            #If both contain things, delete and append
            if (int(result1[0]) > 0) and (int(result2[0]) > 0): 
                arcpy.DeleteRows_management(outFCpath)
                arcpy.Append_management(inFCpath,outFCpath,'NO_TEST')
                print ("Deleted and Re-appended " + fc)

            #If outFCpath emty and inFCpath contains features, just append
            elif (int(result1[0]) < 1)and (int(result2[0]) > 0):
                arcpy.Append_management(inFCpath,outFCpath,'NO_TEST')
                print ("Appended " + fc)

            #If both empty, print empty
            else:
                print (outFCpath + " and " + inFCpath + " are both Empty")   

        else:
            print (outFCpath + " Does Not Exist")


for tbl in arcpy.ListTables():
    inTBLpath = os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, tbl)
    outTBLpath = os.path.join(sdeWS, 'GIO.' + tbl)
    
    if arcpy.Exists(outTBLpath):
        result = arcpy.GetCount_management(outTBLpath)
        result4 = arcpy.GetCount_management(inTBLpath)

        #If both contain things, delete and append
        if (int(result[0]) > 0) and (int(result4[0]) > 0):
            arcpy.DeleteRows_management(outTBLpath)
            arcpy.Append_management(inTBLpath,outTBLpath,'NO_TEST')
            print ("Deleted and Re-appended " + tbl)
                
        #If outFCpath emty and inFCpath contains features, just append
        elif (int(result[0]) < 1) and (int(result4[0]) > 0):
            arcpy.Append_management(inTBLpath,outTBLpath,'NO_TEST')
            print ("Appended " + tbl)

        #If both empty, print empty
        else:
            print (outTBLpath + " and " + inTBLpath + " are both Empty") 

    else:
        print (outTBLpath + " Does Not Exist")
```

This is my current code block and its failing at the first try statement.

Comment: Does `outFCpath` conform to the requirements of the truncate tool as discussed in the help file for the tool under usage section?

Comment: @Hornbydd yes it gives me count then right to the except

Comment: the parameter for truncateTable is a feature class which is stored in outFCpath

Comment: But have you read the usage section...

Comment: ah, it is a versioned data. I changed it to deleteRows_management, and its still giving me the count then the exception @Hornbydd

Comment: Remove the `try` line and the `except` clauses.  Then you will see what the real error is.

Comment: Read how to use getCount tool help

Comment: arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000582: Error occurred during execution. this is the error i get when i removed the try statement @SonofaBeach

Comment: Edit your original question (using the 'Edit' link below it) to show your updated code AND include the FULL text of the entire error stack.

Comment: @SonofaBeach updated the code and the current error.

Comment: If you run the Delete Rows tool on the same feature class in ArcMap, what happens?

Comment: What happens if you switch to delete features for the feature classes instead of delete rows? https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/delete-features.htm